# How to add a localization in XCode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, localization

Currently I am trying to add localizations to my app. The problem is that I do not have localization under my apps info and I am not able to add localization via Editor -> Add Localization. Here are some screenshots to show you my problem:

[image: Via Editor]

[image: Via App Info]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was to not select AlleNeune.app as target but the project "AlleNeune" switching to this, I got the correct info for localizations and was able to add them.